# What is a standard name for a "relation" as a subset of $X\times \mathcal P(X)$ rather than of $X\times X$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology, relations

(Binary) relations on $X$ are formalized as subsets of $X\times X$.

But there are also times when a "relation" is a subset of $X\times \mathcal P(X)$. For example, in topology, we may say that $x$ is in the closure of $X$, and consider this as a relation, and write $x<X$.

**Is there a standard name for such a point-to-set "relation"?**

Comment: Maybe of interest to you, however, for the reverse order, i.e. for $\mathcal P(X)\times X$: In mathematical logic, when you have a formal language $\mathcal L$, which members are designated as formulas, you study relations, where you say that a formula $\phi$ is derivable from a set $\Gamma$ of formulas, written e.g. $\Gamma\vdash\phi$. Such a relations, however induced, are often called  consequence relations or derivability relations.

Comment: I can't think of a name in general.  If I were trying to do this, I would just describe the relation that I'm thinking of.

Comment: I think this is more related to elementary set theory; closures in topology just serves as an example. That's why I retagged it. Feel free to roll back.

Comment: In *Practical Foundations of Mathematics* Paul Taylor calls a relation $R\subset \mathcal{P}(X)\times X$ a "system of closure conditions on $X$", and considers them as general structures that give rise to induction principles.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know that there's a standard name for them. But you could call them *unary quantifiers.* To explain why will take a bit of exposition. You may want to make yourself a cup of tea and get comfortable, as this will take a some time.

**Part 0.** If $Y$ is a set, we can speak of the *quantifiers* on $Y$, which I define as the elements of $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(Y))$. The two most well-known quantifier families are:

$$\forall_Y := \{A \subseteq Y : \forall y \in Y(y \in A)\}, \qquad \exists_Y := \{A \subseteq Y : \exists y \in Y(y \in A)\}.$$

The reason the above definitions are natural are because they gives us the following equivalences:

$$\forall(y \in Y) P(y) \iff \{y \in Y : P(y)\} \in \forall_Y$$

$$\exists(y \in Y) P(y) \iff \{y \in Y : P(y)\} \in \exists_Y$$

But there's heaps of other examples, of course. For example, a topology on $X$ is a quantifier on $X$ satisfying two axioms.

We can use this observation to invent our own quantifiers. For example, suppose $\tau$ is the standard topology on the real line. Then, simulating the above equivalences, we can write:
$$\tau(y \in \mathbb{R}) P(y) \iff \{y \in \mathbb{R} : P(y)\} \in \tau$$

For example, the statement
$$\forall(a,b \in \mathbb{R}) \tau(y \in \mathbb{R}) : a < y < b$$
is basically saying that the interval $(a,b)$ is an open set.

**Part 1.** If $Y$ is a set, we can speak of the elements of $Y$, which are basically the same thing as functions $1 \rightarrow Y$. More generally, we can speak of function $X \rightarrow Y$, where $X$ is an index set on the element of $Y$ depends. If so, then maybe having two words for "function" and "element" is somehow a mistake. A function is just a dependent element. An element is a just a function whose domain of dependence is trivial. They're gesturing at exactly the same concept; why have two words?

Similarly, if $Y$ is a set, we can also speak of the subsets of $Y$, which are basically the same thing as functions $1 \rightarrow \mathcal{P}(Y)$. More generally, we can speak of subsets that are dependent on an index set $X$. These are functions $X \rightarrow \mathcal{P}(Y)$, where $X$ is the domain upon which our subsets are depending. Such things are usually called relations, and often defined as elements of $\mathcal{P}(X \times Y)$. Indeed, it is a general fact that $$X \rightarrow \mathcal{P}(Y) \cong \mathcal{P}(X \times Y).$$ This may look strange, but it's not too surprising when rewritten as $$(2^Y)^X \cong 2^{X \times Y}.$$ A good exercise is to write down this bijection explicitly.

Anyway, in light of this, maybe having two words for "subset" and "relation" is a mistake. A subset of $Y$ is just a relation $1 \rightarrow Y$. A relation from $X$ to $Y$ is just a subset of $Y$ dependent on $X$. They're gesturing at exactly the same concept; why have two words?

Now, perhaps you see where I'm going with this. As mentioned previously, if $Y$ is a set, we can also speak of the quantifiers on $Y$, which are basically the same thing as functions $1 \rightarrow \mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(Y))$. Supposing we want to generalize this so that dependence on a set $X$ is allows. We're looking for a name to give to functions $X \rightarrow \mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(Y))$. Whatever are we to call them? Let's make good on our previous observations that there's really just too many words for things and just call them quantifiers.

**Definition.** A *quantifier* $X \rightarrow Y$ is a function $X \rightarrow \mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(Y))$.

We recover the previous definition by taking $X = 1$, and we recover the concept you're interested in by taking $X = Y$.

"Hang on", you may say. "That's not what I'm interested in. I'm interested in a name for the elements of the set $\mathcal{P}(X \times \mathcal{P}(X))$. You've essentially given me a name for the elements of the set $X \rightarrow \mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(X))$. These are not the same!"

"Aha!" says I. "Go and look at that bijection you wrote down earlier. It puts these two sets into natural correspondence!"

**Part 2.** Here's some existing terminology that's worth being aware of:

> **Accepted Terminology.**
>
> A nullary function on $X$ is a function $1 \rightarrow X$.
>
> A unary function on $X$ is a function $X \rightarrow X$.
>
> A binary function on $X$ is a function $X^2 \rightarrow X$.

etc.

It's tempting to apply this terminology to relations, too as in:

> **Terminology that won't work.**
>
> A nullary relation on $X$ is a function $1 \rightarrow \mathcal{P}(X)$.
>
> A unary relation on $X$ is a function $X \rightarrow \mathcal{P}(X)$.
>
> A binary relation on $X$ is a function $X^2 \rightarrow \mathcal{P}(X)$.

It doesn't work because what we're calling a unary relation above would actually be regarded as a binary relation by most authors. This forces us to invent a new phrase: "multivalued function". For example, we can then speak of a "unary multivalued function on $X$," which is the same thing as a binary relation on $X$.

There are no such issues with extrapolating to the world of quantifiers, however, because we just made the terminology up, so there's really no standards!

> **Proposed New Terminology.**
>
> A nullary quantifier on $X$ is a function $1 \rightarrow \mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(X))$.
>
> A unary quantifier on $X$ is a function $X \rightarrow \mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(X))$.
>
> A binary function on $X$ is a function $X^2 \rightarrow \mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(X))$.

etc.

Thus since a unary quantifier on $X$ is a function $X \rightarrow \mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(X))$, and since we a previous argument this is the same as an element of $\mathcal{P}(X \times \mathcal{P}(X))$, I propose that you can call such things unary quantifiers.

Comment: +1 for my cup of tea. I haven't read the post.